# iOS: update constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have this code to update constraints for a `UITextFiled`

```
- (void)updateUIOnePassword {

  NSLayoutConstraint *fullTextField = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.passwordTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.userIdTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
  NSLayoutConstraint *cutTextField = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.passwordTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.userIdTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-60.0f];

  if ([self isOnepasswordAvailable]) {
    self.onepasswordButton.alpha = 1.0f;
    [self.view removeConstraint:fullTextField];
    [self.view addConstraint:cutTextField];
  } else {
    self.onepasswordButton.alpha = 0.0f;
    [self.view addConstraint:fullTextField];
    [self.view updateConstraints];
  }

  [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

when `isOnepasswordAvailable` is TRUE at start, it works fine, after when I delete OP app and `isOnepasswordAvailable` is FALSE works well again, but when I enter again in `isOnepasswordAvailable` when id TRUE the constraints don't work fine anymore and I have some warning in the consolle.
Do you know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though I always prefer having an IBOutlet to constraint, you have created a constraint programmatically I believe there must be a good reason for that :)

Couple of issues I noticed,

1> I checked both of your constraints, only thing those constraints vary is in their constant values. I believe you dont have to create two different constraint and add and remove them based on condition. Looks very much complicated.

you can have a property named

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSLayoutConstraint *textFieldConstraint;
```

and in `viewWillAppear`

```
 if ([self isOnepasswordAvailable]) {
       self.textFieldConstraint  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.passwordTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.userIdTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
}
else {
     self.textFieldConstraint  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.passwordTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.userIdTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-60.0f];
}
[self.view addConstraint:self.textFieldConstraint];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

2> Update the method `updateUIOnePassword` as

```
- (void)updateUIOnePassword {
  if ([self isOnepasswordAvailable]) {
    self.onepasswordButton.alpha = 1.0f;
    self.textFieldConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
  } else {
    self.onepasswordButton.alpha = 0.0f;
    self.textFieldConstraint.constant = -0.60f;
  }
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This should do the job :) Have look buddy :)

Comment: This is good if I want update the same constraints, but if I want to change the constraints? so remove it and add another one different?

Comment: I understand buddy :) but in your question the two constraint you were removing and adding had difference only on their constant value :) so specifically for this case I suggested updating constraint rather than adding and removing them :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)updateUIOnePassword {

  NSLayoutConstraint *fullTextField = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.passwordTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.userIdTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
  NSLayoutConstraint *cutTextField = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.passwordTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.userIdTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-60.0f];

  if ([self isOnepasswordAvailable]) {
    self.onepasswordButton.alpha = 1.0f;
    [self.view removeConstraint:fullTextField]; //Invalid statement
    [self.view addConstraint:cutTextField];
  } else {
    self.onepasswordButton.alpha = 0.0f;
    [self.view addConstraint:fullTextField]; 
    [self.view updateConstraints];
  }

  [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

You have an invalid statement. - updateUIOnePassword() gets called `fullTextField` is not have added as constrain and its just an allocation.

meaning you are trying to remove the object which does not present in the array (Array of constraints)

Now my suggestion is, Make a class level instance of  `cutTextField` and `fullTextField` add them only once.

when you don't need it

`[fullTextField setActive:NO];`

When you need to modify

```
[fullTextField setActive:YES]; //if already set to NO
[fullTextField setConstant:100];
```